# Review board 's post-review can't work with git,why?

Tags: git, review-board

I finally set up a git and review board server.

I am sure Git works fine,client machine can pull/push files!

Review board server works fine too.I can create a new request manually on web page and another guy can see the review request from email.

We have two machines,A has a git remote server and review board server. B is my working machine--Ubuntu desktop,also has a git system.

When I run post-review in one git test project on B,got this error:

```
post-review
```

Error uploading diff

The generated diff file was empty. This usually means no files were
modified in this change.

Try running with --output-diff and --debug for more information.

Your review request still exists, but the diff is not attached.

why?

Comment: used this command:"git diff --color > foo.txt" to generate a diff file first

executed "post-review --diff-filename=foo.txt -d",but still got this:

Error uploading diff

Your review request still exists, but the diff is not attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself.Because when configuring git path in review board admin page,don't use git@server:yourproject.git format,must use the file path of local git project folder in repositories.
For example:
/home/git/repositories/maventest.git
also my review board dependencies lighttpd,configure lighttpd.conf to make it run as git user.
Somebody said that mirror path in git configuration of review board admin page should use  git@server:yourproject.git format.I tried,but suggest you should import a private key in SSH setting page of review board.
Hope it could help others.